# variable is not found in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I have written the following code to create a directory where the directory name will look like "nowt_hour_nimute_second". But the code is failing in Bash Shell.

```
#THIS CODE WILL CREATE A DIRECTORY WITH TIME OF CREATION AS PART OF DIRECTORY NAME
#AUTHOR: SUBIR ADHIKARI
#DATE: 02/12/2014

echo "The time is $(date +%H_%M_%S)"
now=$(date +%H_%M_%S)
echo $now
echo $(pwd)
createdep=nowt_$now
echo $(createdep)
mkdir createdep
```

On executing, I am getting the following output...

```
The time is 01_12_30
01_12_30
/home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix
createfiles.sh: 10: createfiles.sh: createdep: not found
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the error says: createdep is not a program.

Change this:

```
echo $(createdep)
mkdir createdep
```

to this:

```
echo "$createdep"
mkdir "$createdep"
```

Note that the format string for `date` can contain regular characters too, so you don't need the "now" variable:

```
createdep=$(date +"nowt_%H_%M_%S")
```

Comment: It would be very helpful of you if you can just show the difference between `echo $(createdep)` and `echo "$createdep"`. I was under the impression in case of echo `"` is not necessary.

Comment: `$(createdep)` starts a subshell and attempts to run the program named "createdep" (see [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) in the manual). The difference between quotes and no quotes is that quotes will prevent [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion)...

Comment: If $createdep contains "foo<tab>bar", then `echo $createdep` (no quotes) will only display a single space between foo and bar. If $createdep contains "*", then `echo $createdep` (no quotes) will display all the filenames in the current directory

Comment: You may be thinking of `echo ${createdeps}` (with curly braces). That is **not** the same as using double quotes. As the manual says: "The parameter name or symbol to be expanded may be enclosed in braces, which are optional but serve to protect the variable to be expanded from characters immediately following it which could be interpreted as part of the name."